# unable to open a csv with fortran

Tags: csv, fortran

I am trying to read an input from csv file (input.csv, in the same folder of this f95 file) which has some numbers in certain columns. while I execute my program, it gives error

```
 program received signal SIGSEGV: segmentation fault - invalid memory reference. backtrace =#0 ffffffff
```

the code is below; it terminates after the first print statement.

```
program section

implicit none

integer::no_num,count_le,count_cve,count_cvx,count_ce

integer::i,j

double precision,allocatable,dimension(:)::x1,y1,x2,y2

double precision,allocatable,dimension(:)::xc,yc,rc,sa,ea

character (2),allocatable,dimension(:):: asc,asl,sd

character(100)::rand_char ! random characters/txt

print*,"program"

open(unit=100,file='input.csv')

print*,"check"



close(100)

end program
```

Comment: Please compile your program for debugging and always test your programs like that if they crash. Like `gfortran -g -fbacktrace -Wall -fcheck=all` or `ifort -g -traceback -warn -check`.

Comment: *which has some numbers in certain columns* That is really not enough, please show us an actual sample of that file. See [mcve].

Comment: hi, thanks , I just put the flags -g, -fcheck=all, -wall, -W.. when I now run, what should I look for

Comment: You should look how the output changes. Especially the error messages. Copy and paste the **complete** output here. Also tell use your operatingsystem and compiler versions.

Comment: the built log as below;  Checking for existence: C:\general-codes\Fortran\bin\Debug\greens_section.exe
Executing: "C:\Program Files (x86)\CodeBlocks/cb_console_runner.exe" "C:\general-codes\Fortran\bin\Debug\greens_section.exe"  (in C:\general-codes\Fortran\.)
Process terminated with status -1073741510 (0 minute(s), 3 second(s))
 
I am using codeblocks with gnu fortrancompiler on win10 (64 bit)

Comment: Not just the build log. Re-run the program and copy and paste the complete output by [edit] into the question. Do not use comments for important information.

Comment: hi, I am using codeblocks and when I run the program, it opens it command prompt. the error is the same as in my question      ; program received signal SIGSEGV: segmentation fault - invalid memory reference. backtrace =#0 ffffffff                                how can I give more information to you, please guide

Comment: Try to run it in the command line. Make sure you are running the correct executable  - compiled with the right flags.

Comment: hi, I don't know how to run from command prompt. my compiler is gnu fortran compiler in codeblocks, how to I get output as you have suggested

Comment: Copy the executable to the right directory, open cmd.exe, navigate to the directory using `cd`, run the executable and copy the output https://www.howtogeek.com/howto/windows-vista/copy-to-the-clipboard-from-the-windows-command-prompt/ This is a must-have skill to have, absolutely necessary and non-negotiable. You can't get far in programming without knowing the very basics of the command line.

Comment: I don't see an `allocate()` command.

Comment: hello ja72, the program is crashing well before all that. if you read through, all the variables are not used at all.. after the first print statement, the program is crashing.

Comment: If you remove the `open(unit=100,file='input.csv')`, does it still crash?

Comment: hi Rodrigo, it works like on butter, if I comment that line. no issues. the print statement after that line showed up when I commented that line. I have input.csv in the same folder

Comment: @Vladimir F, when I ran with from cmd, I get a new error. the msgbox says - ' the code execution cannot proceed because libgcc_s_sjlj-1.dll was not found. reinstalling the program may fix this program, upon giving ok, it mentioned libgfortran-3.dll not found, and then aborted. this appears not connected with my program, because this is happening even if I comment out the line where I am calling the .csv file. the csv file is a simple file with value set as 1 in cell A1. I feel the error is something to do with the way excel is called

Comment: @rodrigo, I am not even trying to read the input file, I changed the file to data.txt where the file had just a character in the contents. still the same error happens.

Comment: @vladimir, this is the output>                                                                              program

Program received signal SIGSEGV: Segmentation fault - invalid memory reference.

Backtrace for this error:
#0  ffffffff

Comment: Excel??? What Excel, you were talking about Code:Blocks, where does the Excel come into play? The program you present here is a correct Fortran program and does not crash for me or other people.

Comment: @Vladimir, I was referring to the line where it is calling the .csv . this .csv was created from excel >save as > msdos csv. I personally don't see an error in the script I have written, however it is crashing only due to that line.

Comment: Try to install a different compiler. Different gfortran version or distribution.

Comment: hi, I just tried codeblocks 16 (I had the latest earlier, which was ver 17) and now the issue is solved. thanks for all the suggestions